# How to make dynamic increasing of divs (div at the top and div at the bottom) repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

If we consider we have a wrapper div that has unknown number of tabs.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div> Tab1 </div>
    <div> Tab2 </div>
    <div> Tab3 </div>
    <div> Tab4 </div>
    <div> Tab5 </div>
    <div> Tab6 </div>
    <div> Tab7 </div>
    <div> Tab1 </div>
    <div> Tab1 </div>
</div>
```

How to dynamically increase Tabs Div? I want the arrangement to be like Div up, Div down then Div up, Div down etc…
Like on the image below.

[image: Grid]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/

Comment: Can u please Answer it so i can Mark it as Answered

Comment: No, I cannot post a mere link as an answer. If it solved your problem, you can post your final solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was in the CSS By the Following Code:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```